# Github Page with NodeJS package as SubModule from sub-directory to sub-directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-pages, git-submodules

***Hi***

I got this NodeJS application that exists in a sub-directory of a repository. I would like to make a simple interface and host it on Github Pages as a submodule.

The problem I'm having is how I would go about that. My package exists in a sub-directory of a separate repository while the page is in another in a sub-directory with the same name. Then there's the problem of running it.

## Repository layout

```
## NodeJS package repository
Shazuli/Node-Packages/MyPackage1

## Page repository
Shazuli/Shazuli.github.io/MyPackage1
```

The actual page is up to me to design, my question is how I would create a submodule from a sub-directory to another sub-directory in a different repository and then use that code from the module on Github Pages. Running a NodeJS package on a website.

I *could* rewrite the program to function in a browser, but that would reduce the flexibility of it. I like to be able to run it in the console and spit out the result into my output file as before, and the Page would simply function as a graphic controller if I have access to a browser and Internet. Having it as a submodule makes it easier to work with in the long run if I made changes to the package repo and not the Page repo.

Comment: "*Running a NodeJS package on a website*" is not possible at all. NodeJs packages run on a server, not on a web page. Additionally, github pages only hosts static websites.

Comment: Hmm... you think I could separate the package into a bunch of functions and then have a function for NodeJS environment only (filesystem operations for example) while the static website uses the separate functions individually and no NodeJS specific functions (`require()`) @Bergi?

Comment: Yes, that seems reasonable. Not using `require`/`export` will be hard though, I recommend you use ES6 modules (or some other module system if you prefer) and transpile/bundle to a web and a nodejs version. You might even find a bundler that supports replacing a `fs` import with a mock file system that you might use on the web, if that is beneficial for your demo.